# Links to pdf-articles or books where there is an information on some linear integral operator

Tags: reference-request, ordinary-differential-equations

Please write me links to pdf-articles or books where there is some information on properties of operators like these:
$$
(Af)(x,y)=\int_{D}\frac{f(z) \, dz}{|x-z| |z-y|}
$$
or
$$
(Bf)(x,y)=\int_D \frac{f(z) \, dz}{|x-z|^{\alpha} |z-y|^\beta}.
$$
Here $z\in D\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$, $D$ is a smooth bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$; $x\in P\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$, $y\in Q\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$; $P\cap Q=\emptyset$, $Q\cap D=\emptyset$, $D\cap P=\emptyset$; $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$; $\alpha>0$, $\beta>0$.

Thank you very much in advance!